# Let $f(x) \in F[x]$ be irreducible (F is a Field). Suppose $f(x) \mid g_1(x)g_2(x)\dots g_k(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) \in F[x]$ be irreducible (F is a Field). Suppose $f(x) \mid g_1(x)g_2(x)\dots g_k(x)$

Prove $\exists i \in [1,k]$ where $f(x)|g_i(x)$

---

(By contradiciton) **Something along the lines**

Assume $\forall i \in [1,k]$ where $f(x) \nmid g_i(x)$ (not div)

So, $$f(x) \nmid g_1(x),\dots, f(x) \nmid g_k(x)$$

$\therefore$ $f(x) \nmid g_1(x)*\dots*g_k(x) $ Contradiction!

---

**(Straight way**)

***Some thm***

if $f(x)$ is irreducible and $f_1(x) \mid g_1(x)g_2(x)$ then $f(x)|g_1(x)  $ or $f(x)|g_2(x)$

Using that **thm** $f(x)|g_1(x)$ or $f(x)|g_2(x)\dots g_k(x)$

$\vdots$

$f(x)\mid g_1(x)$or $f(x)\mid g_2(x) ...$ or $ f(x)\mid g_i(x) ...$ or $ f(x) \mid g_k(x)$

$\therefore$ $\exists i \in [1,k]$ where $f(x)|g_i(x)$

**Something wrong specially with straight way??**

Comment: If you know the result for 2 factors, induction is the way to go, as you start out doing in the second proof. Use induction explicitly though.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So the basis would be the line right after vdots. Then do the induction step. ok

Comment: Use induction on the number of factors. Basis is $n=1$ or $n=2$, use the 2 case to do the induction to a 1 lower number of factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basis**

if $f(x)$ is irreducible and $f_1(x) \mid g_1(x)g_2(x)$ then 
  $$f(x)|g_1(x)   \vee f(x)|g_2(x)$$  $\exists i \in [0,1] : f(x)|g_i(x)$

**Induction** 
For all Integers $k \geq 1$ assume $\exists i \in [0,k] : p(x)\mid g_i(x)$

in other words $f(x)\mid g_1(x) \vee \dots \vee f(x) \mid g_k(x)$

consider $f(x)\mid g_1*\dots*g_k(x)*g_{k+1}(x) $. So,
$$ f(x)\mid g_1(x) \vee \dots \vee f(x)\mid g_{k}(x)g_{k+1}(x) $$ 
Applying **Thm** adds $f(x) | g_{k}(x) \vee f(x) | g_{k+1}(x) $

$\therefore$ $\exists i \in [0,k+1] : p(x)|g_i(x)$)